# Laravel use case for *has many through* relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `participants` where each participant belongs to a conference, which is an entry in the table `conferences`. Further, each participant can provide one answer which are stored in the table `answers`.

Now, I need a query which gets **all the answers** from **all participants** which **belong to the current conference**.

In particular, I would like to paginate the results, thus I am hoping for a more sophisticated approach than to simply fetch all answers and then check if they belong to a participant in this conference.

To be clear, my tables store basically the following information:

- `participants` - `id`, `conference_id`
- `conferences` - `id`
- `answers` - `id`, `participant_id`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use HasManyThrough.
I think the example in the Laravel Doc fits perfect to your case.
[Laravel Doc example](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. But can I paginate the result from this query? Since this would be a collection, I don't know how to do so.

Comment: If u use conference->answers u get an Eloquent/Collection, if u use conference->answers() u get an HasManyTrough Relation wich extends from Builder. so u can just use something like conference->answers()->paginate(15)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasMany` and `hasOne` relation ship of Laravel Eloquent Model, and add more constraint when you use `Eloquent Relation Ship` query (As Laravel document say All Eloquent Relation Ship is query builder, so you can add constraints using `where`) to get results you expect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).